# Origins of Scruffy's accent

Tags: futurama, accent

What is the origin of Scruffy's (the Planet Express janitor) accent?

I noted he says at one point (what sounds to my ear) like:

> Jail's not s' bad.  You can make Sang-Gree-a in the turlet.

I interpret that as:

> Jail is not so bad.  You can make [Sangria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sangria) in the toilet.

My best guess would be South-Eastern United States.  Can anyone confirm, and narrow it down?

Comment: To my knowledge, Dave Herman has never publicly stated what his inspiration for Scruffy's accent was. With that in mind, it probably becomes a case of simply finding the accent that best corresponds with the Scruffy voice. Unless someone can contact Dave Herman and ask him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Scruffy Scruffington](http://theinfosphere.org/Scruffy) is voiced by Actor [Dave Herman](http://theinfosphere.org/David_Herman)

[image]

According to the Futurama "[Infosphere](http://theinfosphere.org/Scruffy)" His accent is a takeoff of [Billy Bob Thorton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Bob_Thornton)'s character; Karl Childers in the movie [Sling Blade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_Blade) which is set in **rural Arkansas**

[image]

There's an interesting video [here](http://www.comedycentral.com/video-clips/1alk75/futurama-the-voices-of-futurama---david-herman-on-scruffy) that has David Herman talking about being "the voice of Scruffy"

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.  Oh well, I think this matter has been well addressed in any case.  ..Have to say I really love the animated GIF of Scruffy with one of his magazines.  Those are classic.  *"Scruffy's gonna' die like he lived.. Uh-huh"*